# Do I need to call Form.Close(), or is it handled for me?

Tags: c#, winforms, garbage-collection

Using C# and WinForms, I have a base menu that calls a variety of forms on button clicks:

```
private void Some_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var someForm = new SomeForm();

            someForm.MdiParent = MenuForm;
            someForm.Show();
            someForm.BringToFront();
        }
```

My concern is memory useage.  When a user click's "x" to close the form, is `Form.Close()` already called when the window closes?  Or, do I need to create an event in order to explicitly call `Form.Close()`?

Comment: No you don't. Unless you are manually closing the `Form` through your code, you don't need to call `Form.Close()`.

Comment: In traditional .NET way, the Close() method of a class calls Dispose().  That applies to the Form class as well.  You *do* need to call Dispose() in some cases, required when you use ShowDialog() instead of Show().  It cannot be automatic because you'd normally obtain the dialog results after the ShowDialog() call.  And properly done by using the *using* statement.  Not the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a user click's "x" to close the form, is `Form.Close()` already called when the window closes?

No, the `FormClosing` event is fired.  `Form.Close` *tells* the system to close the form (the `FormClosing` event is fired in that case as well).

`Close` is  *command*.  `FormClosing` is called *in response to* a command.

Comment: Good enough for me.  Thanks much!